# restricting pointer events to SVG text fill

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I need to restrict pointer events in an SVG  element to the fill of the text only. I do not want the pointer-event to trigger when the user is in the rectangle around the text, but only when the cursor is actually inside the characters themselves. The SVG pointer-event "fill" should work, but for some reason it's not. Can anyone tell me why not, or what would work instead?

In the example below (jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rgfdudst/), the pointer-event is activated when the cursor is between words. I want the pointer-event to only trigger when the mouse is directly on top of the fill of a character:

HTML

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="100px">
  <text x="10"  y="40">
    SVG text styling
  </text>
</svg>
```

CSS
    text {
      pointer-events: fill;
      fill: red;
      font-size: 50px;
      font-family: Arial;
    }

```
text:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: blue; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The individual text glyph is not an element that can be hovered. Unless you separate each character into a separate element.

Comment: I think if you download Firefox 1.5 (Yes really that 1.5 from 2005) that's what you get. It's was really quite funny to try to click on an o and mostly miss but it wasn't a great user experience and in the end we followed the SVG specification and did selection using glyph cell bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `path`'s to define your text. and attach your hover style to those `path`'s

The `text` area is a rectangle, so your event will fire when you enter that rectangle.